# Insert into all columns of int same value

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, linq

In LINQ how do i insert into all columns of type int in a table1 the same number value: 1, without specifying each column with the number (colint1, colint2, colint3, colint4) ?

Comment: Which LINQ are you talking about? Generally, LINQ is for **query** operations.

Comment: I want: all int to have value 1, i don't want to say colint1 = 1, colint2 = 1....etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection with something like this for an object 'o' and a new integer value 'newValue' (sorry, I don't have VS on this machine to test it out):

```
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in o.GetType().GetProperties()) 
{
    if(prop.PropertyType == typeof(int))
        prop.SetValue(o, newValue, null);
}
```

Then just be sure to save your changes

Comment: happy to share, I ran into a very similar situation a while back